# C++ class conversion possible?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class B {
public:
    B(const std::string& str):m_str(str) { }
    B(const B& b):m_str(b.m_str) { }
    B& operator=(const B& b) { m_str = b.m_str; return *this; }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};

main()
{
    std::string a = "abc";
    B b(a);
}
```

class B belongs to the client.  I can't change it and I may not even know its specific name ("B" is simply an example); all I know is there's a client class that accepts a std::string for its constructor.  Now I want to change the type of "a" in main() from std::string to A, as defined below:

```
class A {
public:
      A(const std::string& str):m_str(str) { }
      A(const char *str):m_str(str) { }
      A(const A& a):m_str(a.m_str) { }
      A& operator=(const A& a) { m_str = a.m_str; return *this; }

private:
      std::string m_str;
};
```

So now I have a new main():

```
main()
{
    A a = "abc";
    B b(a);
}
```

This can't compile properly as it is.  Is there anything I can do without changing the new main()?  I can't change class B, and class A should not reference class B in any way.
Thanks!

Comment: "without changing the new main()"  Why?

Answer (score 5):

add an cast operator

```
class A {
public:
   ....
  operator const std::string()
    {
        return m_str;
    }
```

Comment: They are called user-defined conversion functions.

Comment: Cast Operator: () (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y(v=VS.80).aspx). It's a different name for the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Add user-defined conversion function as:

```
class A
{
 public:
    //other code
    operator std::string()
    {
        return m_str;
    }
    //...
};
```

This allows you write these:

```
B b(a); //which is what you want
std::string s = a; //this is also okay;

void f(std::string s) {}

f(a); //a converts into std::string, by calling user-defined conversion function
```

However you cannot write this:

```
 const A ca("hi");
 std::string s = ca; //error
```

Its because `ca` is a `const` object which cannot invoke non-const user-defined conversion function.

Note the user-defined conversion function returns the string *by value* which means it returns a *copy* of the original string. So you may want to avoid this by defining it as:

```
operator const std::string &() const
{
     return m_str;
}
```

Now, with this you can write this:

```
const A ca("hi");
std::string s = ca; //ok

A a("hi");
std::string s = a; //ok
```

Comment: ouch!  My bad!  I have written a conversion function from A to B (which is not allowed) but for some reason the simpler solution evaded me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int main() //note the correct declaration of main
{
    A a = "abc";
    B b(a.GetString()); //GetString returns m_str;
}
```

By the way, all your definitions of copy constructors and copy-assignment operators coincide with the definitions the compiler would have auto-generated for you.

***Edit***
I just noticed your constraint that `main()` should not change. In this case you can define a [conversion function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr385.htm) from A to string (but it can be dangerous, note).

```
class A
{
    ...
    operator std::string() const {return m_str; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to class A:

```
operator std::string () { return m_str; }
```